# Why GetComponent on Dropdown doesn't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I'm doing settings section in my game, and there is a screen mode dropdown. I did 2 variables of dropdown, because when i try match dropdown variable and dropdown game object, it doesn't work. So, i match dropdown game object as GameObject, then i get dropdown component from dropdown game object by GetComponent. But, unity gives me an error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
What did i do wrong?
There is the code:

```
public GameObject ddgo;
public Dropdown dd;
void Start() {
dd = ddgo.GetComponent<Dropdown>(); 
}
public void DDScreenMode() {
    if (dd.value == 0) {
      Screen.fullScreen = true;
      Debug.Log("Dropdown value fullscreen!");
   }
   if (dd.value == 1) {
       Screen.fullScreen = false;
       Debug.Log("Dropdown value window!");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the dropdown component is on the ddgo gameobject not a child of it (if it is a child use `GetComponentInChildren<Dropdown>()` instead), if it is all good check if you gave ddgo the right gameOBject

Answer (score 0):

`.GetComponent<Dropdown>()` can only get gameObject's own component.

If you want to get component in child gameOjbect,

you should use `GetComponentInChildren<T>()` instead of `GetComponent<T>()`

Check if `GameObject ddgo` has `Dropdown` script.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer. I had TMP dropdown, not usual. But thank you for trying to help me!